# How to write an ArrayList without brackets

Tags: java, java-8

I want to create a csv file with a comma as a delimiter.
I tried to following code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> m_arrAllStats= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
pw.println("");
m_arrAllStats
    .stream()
    .filter(m -> (m.size() > 0))
    .forEach(s -> pw.print(s + ","));

pw.println("");
pw.close();
```

but what I get is the data wrapped within square brackets:

> [20/06 We, 20:00,  amina,  Dugus, aqqa, kksia, 1, 8, 39, 14, 25, 15,
>   17, 12, 3, 3, 5, 0, 9],

How can I fix that?

Comment: Your question is unclear and does not contain all needed data to form an adequate answer. You are completely missing the details of what `m_arrAllStats` contains. And you are very broad on the actual problem and didn't show us the output. Please **edit** your question to provide what is needed (see [ask] and [help]).

Comment: @Zabuza Edited.

Comment: Better. But you are still missing the details on what `m_arrAllStats` contains or how it's constructed. Also, what is its type?

Comment: It's impossible for your code to produce a result like that. It will always append a comma at the end.

Comment: If `m_arrAllMatchesStats` and `m_arrAllStats` are actually the same array then `s` in `forEach` is an ArrayList and not a String

Comment: @Turing85, thanks. Typing to fast :)

Comment: From what I see, I would suspect that `m_arrAllStats` is some kind of `List<List<...>>`. The `toString()`-methods of `List`-implementation normally returns a representation in the form of `[ <value> (, <value)*]`. Write your own utility-method to transform the `List`s in a `String`-representation you want.

Comment: @Besh Gurung You are correct. I missed the last comma AFTER the right bracket...

Comment: Guys I am sorry for the typoes. The code and output are presented correctly now.

Comment: "*Don't be sorry, be better.*" - Kratos

Comment: Your list s a list of lists. You're iterating on each inner list of the outer list, and printing it. So you get lists separated by commas. What you want is to transform each inner list into elements separated by commas, and then print reach result separated by newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing a list instead of the elements of the list.  Something like this should work.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> m_arrAllStats= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
pw.println("");
m_arrAllStats
    .stream()
    .filter(m -> (m.size() > 0))
    .forEach(s -> pw.print(String.join(",", s)));

pw.println("");
pw.close();
```

Comment: Thank you Bakon. It seems to be good. I will check it in a few minutes and if correct I'll be happy to accept it as an answer :)

Comment: Excellent!  Just add another right bracket after the join and before the semicolon :)